# Install RJulia package in R

Tags: r, julia

I am trying to install RJulia package on windows:

Julia Version: 0.4

R Version: 3.2.1

RStudio Version: 0.99.467

You may find the relevant `R` code:

```
library(devtools)
Sys.setenv(JULIA_SRC="C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Julia-0.4.0-rc1")
Sys.setenv(LD_LIBRARY_PATH=":/Users/user/AppData/Local/Julia-0.4.0-rc1/lib/julia")
devtools::install_github("armgong/RJulia", ref="0.4")# or ref="0.4" if using Julia v0.4
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
julia: not found
julia: not found
gcc -m32 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I/../../src -I/../../src/support -I/../include -I/../include/julia -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600    -I"d:/RCompile/r-compiling/local/local320/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c Julia_R.c -o Julia_R.o
Julia_R.c:13:19: fatal error: julia.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Julia_R.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.1/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="rjulia.dll" OBJECTS="Julia_R.o R_Julia.o dataframe.o embedding.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rjulia'
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: can you run julia? is it in your path? did you try for stable?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Julia runs fine and its path is also in the system environment PATH. I tried also using the stable version. I am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-installed the latest version of RStudio 0.99.484  and re-configured the system PATH following @rawr advice (I had two installation paths of julia v.0.4 and v.0.3.11 and I kept the stable version) and it seems to work.